# Learning Python, scripts for other project

Tags: python

**Question:** I am having some issues with my old scripts that do not work on Python 3.x

Offtopic; how flexible is Python when trying to access binary and text files for mass renaming, renumbering? within Collision and IMG archives?

I do not have the best understanding of this anymore as I have gone the direction of Level design using 3dsmax.

Anyway..

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\SOL_REM.py", line 26, in <module>
    process_ide(sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]),
  File "C:\SOL_REM.py", line 18, in process_ide
    ide_line = reduce(lambda x,y: str(x)+","+st
NameError: global name 'reduce' is not defined
```

**Code:**

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 4:
    sys.exit('Usage: Source ide | ID number | Dest ide filename.' sys.argv[0])

def process_ide(ide_source, num, ide_destination):
    src = open(ide_source,'r')
    dst = open(ide_destination,'w')

    for line in src:
        ide_line = line

        if not (line == "" or line[0]=="#" or len(line.split(",")) < 2):
            ide_line = line.split(",")
            ide_line[-1] = ide_line[-1][:-2]
            ide_line[0] = num
            num+=1
            ide_line = reduce(lambda x,y: str(x)+","+str(y), ide_line)+"\n"

        dst.write(ide_line)

    src.close()
    dst.close()


process_ide(sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]), sys.argv[3])
```

**Starting out simple:**

What I am trying to do is parse an ide text file by changing numbers in enumerate order.

Syntax would be SOL_rem.py game.ide 1845 game2.ide

**Example file:**

```
ID    Modelname     TexName       Rendering flags.

objs
1700, ap_booth2_03, ap_airstuff1, 1, 190, 0
1701, ap_seaplaland1, ap_seasplane, 1, 299, 0
1702, ap_seaplanehanger1, ap_seasplane, 1, 299, 0
1703, ap_termwindows1, ap_termwindows, 1, 299, 4
1704, ap_blastdef_01, ap_newprops1opac, 1, 299, 4
1705, ap_blastdef_03, ap_newprops1opac, 1, 299, 4
1706, air_brway_030, airgrndb, 1, 299, 0
end
```

The IDs would be re-adjusted from 1845 in ascending order.

Comment: What version of Python is this? And what does this error have to do with how "flexible" Python is?

Comment: If you use the tools that come with Python (like say, the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)), its even more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

`reduce` is no longer in the builtin namespace in Python 3.

Instead of using `reduce`, why not just use a `join`?

```
ide_line = ','.join(ide_line) + '\n'
```

Comment: File "C:\SOL_REM.py", line 27
  process_ide(sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]), sys.argv[3]) sys - this a result of adding from functools import reduce

Comment: Why don't you add that traceback to your question?

Answer (score 0):

In Python3, you can do

```
from functools import reduce
```

And even in Python2.6+ the above should be okay, but is not required.

Yes. Python is totally flexible for whatever you want to do. Like overriding builtins too.

Comment: Oh did not notice that. He is using Python3.

Comment: Thank you, trying this without success.

Comment: 2.6 the scripts worked fine, I could have done a better job like just inputting the number of the desired ID and a file requester for picking the source and dest file.